# Read a string and create an acronym from the first initial letter of every word on the string

Tags: string, matlab

I just wrote a code with the criteria above, but it doesn't seem to work properly because I either miss a letter at the end or in the middle.

Could anyone please check out my code an tell me what I'm doing wrong. By the way I already checked other threads on this similar problem, but I'm not allowed to use `regex` or `print` function.

```
phrase=('my room is cold')
allSpaces=findstr(' ',phrase);
k=length(allSpaces)
acr=phrase(1:allSpaces(1):allSpaces(k)-1)
```

Output:

```
acr= mrms
```

Comment: Shouldn't your output be `mric`?

Comment: Yeah,but the last line of my code is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change last line to

```
acr = phrase([1 allSpaces+1])
```

That way you get the first letter, and then the first after each space.

Comment: Thanks. But could you please explain what happens in that line, I know that the 1 means to start at position one then adding 1 position to the blank spaces. how come there is not semicolon, but there is a space between the 1 and the allspaces ?

Comment: @KururugiSuzaku A comma or a space are equivalent: they concatenate horizontally. In this case, if `allSpaces` is a 1x3 vector, the expression `[1 allSpaces+1]` gives a 4x1 vector. If `allSpaces` were a _column_ vector (of size 3x1 for example), you would have to concatenate _vertically_, using a semicolon: `[1; allSpaces+1]`, which would give a 4x1 vector.

Comment: Welcome! In my previous comment, when I wrote "`[1 allSpaces+1]` gives a 4x1 vector" I meant "`[1 allSpaces+1]` gives a 1x4 vector".